# Using list comprehension to automatically populate a list with specific data type

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list-comprehension

I got a simple data in a CSV file. This data has both categorical and continuous columns. This is how I'm separating them:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

categorical_columns = ['order_id', 'start_state_abr', 'end_state_abr', 'start_city', 'end_city', 'start_zip', 'end_zip']
continuous_columns = ['total_volume_inches3', 'total_distance_miles', 'total_weight_lbs']
```

This is too manual. It requires the programmer to read the CSV file each time there is a new column. Is there a way to populate the lists `categorical_columns` and `continuous_columns` using list comprehension?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you please show me the CSV?
I suppose that you could figure out the type of columns by eyes, but just don't know how to pick them up by automatic function! The solutions are as follows!

```
# distinguish the categorical_columns,numerical_columns:
# 1.use df.info() to check out which columns are 'object' 
df.info()

# 2.then use df.select_dtypes(excluede=['object']).columns to get numerical columns
numerical_col=list(tf.select_dtypes(exclude=['object']).columns)
categorical_col = []
for i in train.columns:
  if i not in numerical_col:
      categorical_col.append(i)
categorical_col 

# 3.Furthermore,distinguish the serial columns and noserial columns:
numerical_serial_col=[]
numerical_noserial_col=[]
for i in numerical_col:
  if train[i].nunique()<=10:
      numerical_noserial_col.append(i)
  else:
      numerical_serial_col.append(i)
numerical_serial_col,numerical_noserial_col
```

[This is my first answer in stack-overflow, please forgive me for the Nonstandard answer format !]